# Put Background Images on HTML links

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get social icons to be displayed on the footer through CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="copyright container">
  <div class="sicons">
    <a class="copy1" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy2" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy3" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy4" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy5" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0em auto;
  width: 1000px;
}
.copyright {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1em 0em;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}
.copyright a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.copyright img {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}
.copyright a.copy5 img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.copyright a.copy1 {
  background: url(1.png) center no-repeat;
}
.copyright a.copy2 {
  background: url(2.png) center no-repeat;
}
.copyright a.copy3 {
  background: url(2.png) center no-repeat;
}
.copyright a.copy4 {
  background: url(4.png) center no-repeat;
}
.copyright a.copy5 {
  background: url(5.png) center no-repeat;
}
```

The images will not show with the code like this. They will show when I add

```
.copyright a.copy1, .copyright a.copy2, .copyright a.copy3, .copyright a.copy4, .copyright a.copy5 { 
  display: inline-block; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  margin:15px; 
  text-indent:-9999px; 
  width:50px; 
  height:50px; 
}
```

But the images come out looking distorted with this code. Where I'm I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start how to do.

```css
.copyright a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}
.copyright a.copy2, .copyright a.copy4 {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/80/80/sports/);
}
.copyright a.copy1, .copyright a.copy3, .copyright a.copy5 {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/80/80/);
}
```

```html
<div class="copyright container">
  <div class="sicons">
    <a class="copy1" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy2" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy3" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy4" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy5" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If different image size, this show that and still keep the anchor size equal.

```css
.copyright a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: contain;
}
.copyright a.copy2, .copyright a.copy4 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/80/160/sports/);
}
.copyright a.copy1, .copyright a.copy3, .copyright a.copy5 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/160/80/);
}
```

```html
<div class="copyright container">
  <div class="sicons">
    <a class="copy1" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy2" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy3" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy4" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy5" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here the image fills its containers background, which of course does clip them, some at height, some at width, as they are set to keep their ratio.

```css
.copyright a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.copyright a.copy2, .copyright a.copy4 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/80/160/sports/);
}
.copyright a.copy1, .copyright a.copy3, .copyright a.copy5 {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/160/80/);
}
```

```html
<div class="copyright container">
  <div class="sicons">
    <a class="copy1" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy2" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy3" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy4" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy5" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the pictures I'm using are coming out distorted

Comment: @MaxNjoroge What does that mean? .. that they are not same size/width/height?

Comment: I'm using PNG files, the image is coming out zoomed in

Comment: @MaxNjoroge What you mean by "coming out zoomed in"? ... Btw, updated my answer with a few more samples when using different image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

First off, your `.copyright img` class is not being used in this example. For keeping your code clean, I recommend removing it if you're not putting any images inside the `.copyright` div.

Without a doubt, you will need to set up the `width` and `height` to make empty `<a></a>` background visible. In addition, I would recommend adding an empty spacer (`&nbsp;`) inside your `<a>` tags, just to make sure they will appear in your web page since they are not empty.

Also, `display: inline-block;` **can be vital** to your setup, but using margin with this can cause a mess. If you need to add something inside your links, you should use padding or absolute positioned element inside your link.

In need of any further assistance, I would like to get a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your code, along with some pictures taken from Google etc. as placeholders.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the image a link. Try something like this:

```
 <div class="copyright container">
     <div class="sicons">
         <a class="copy1" href="#"><img  src="1.png"></a>
         <a class="copy2" href="#"><img src="2.png"></a>
         <a class="copy3" href="#"><img src="3.png"></a>
         <a class="copy4" href="#"><img src="4.png"></a>
        <a class="copy5" href="#"><img src="5.png"></a>
      </div> 
 </div>
```

But of course if you want to keep the text you can always title you images and make the title the link to follow. This is easily achievable by simply placing a div with a linked title inside it and overlaying above the chosen image.

Comment: I am currently using that but I want to change

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, I prefer put a picture with :after attribute. Like this pictures are more flexible, if you change `<a>` width it will work, she is have to higher than picture's width.  However, ProDexorite's answer is good too :)

```css
.copyright a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
}

.copyright a:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.copyright > .sicons > .copy2:after,
.copyright > .sicons > .copy1:after,
.copyright > .sicons > .copy3:after,
.copyright > .sicons > .copy4:after,
.copyright > .sicons > .copy5:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/80/80/sports/);
}
```

```html
<div class="copyright container">
  <div class="sicons">
    <a class="copy1" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy2" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy3" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy4" href="#"></a>
    <a class="copy5" href="#"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```